# Efficient processing of custom data by actors

Tags: scala, akka

I am an Akka newbie trying things out for a particular problem. I am trying to write code for an actor system which would efficiently process custom data coming from multiple clients in the form of events. By custom data, I mean, the content and structure of the data would vary between events from the same client (e.g., we might have instrumented to drop 5 events containing 5 different piece of information for the same client), and between events from different clients (e.g., we might be capturing completely different set of information from one client vs. another). I am wondering what would be a good way to use actor-based processing for this type of scenarios.

This are the alternatives what I have thought so far:

(A) I will write an actor which would load client-specific processor class through reflection, based on the client whose event is being processed. The client-specific processor class would contain logic corresponding to all the type of events that would be received for that client. I will initiate 'n' instances of this actor.

```
context.actorOf(Props[CustomEventProcessor].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = 100)), name = "CustomProcessor")
```

(B) I will write actors for each client, each containing logic corresponding to all the type of events that would be received for that client. I will initiate 'n' instances of each of these actors.

```
context.actorOf(Props[CleintXEventProcessor].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = 50)), name = "ClientXCustomProcessor")
context.actorOf(Props[CleintYEventProcessor].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = 50)), name = "ClientYCustomProcessor")
```

At this point, I have a few questions:

1. Would [A] be slower compared to [B] becuase [A] is using reflection? I am assuming that once an actor instance has finished processing a particular event, it dies, so the next actor instance processing an event from the same client would have to start with loading the processor class again. Is this assumption correct?
2. Given a specific event flow pattern, would a system based on [B] have a heavier runtime memory footprint compared to [A] becuase now each actor for each client can have multiple instances of them in memory?
3. Any other way to approach this problem?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

1. It could be a bit slower, but I think not really noticeable. And no, you don't have to kill actors between events.
2. No, because single actor takes like 400 bytes in memory, so you can create a single actor for each event, not only one actor per client.
3. Yes, via Reactive Streams which I think is a bit clearer solution than actors, but Akka Streams are still experimental, and it may be a bit harder to learn than actors. But you'll have backpressure for free if its needed.

Comment: Akka Streams will not be experimental in Akka 2.4.2 (currently in RC3)